# ($_FILES array is empty) error on saving image in admin - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, module, image-upload

Magento Save Custom Image In Backend

```
public function saveAction()
{
    if ( $this->getRequest()->getPost() ) {
        try {

            $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('img');
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png')); // Your Format Here
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
            $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'Gallery'.DS;
            $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['img']['name']);
            $img = $_FILES['img']['name'];
            $galleryModel = Mage::getModel('gallery/gallery');                
            $galleryModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                ->setTitle($postData['title'])
                ->setDescription($postData['description'])
                ->setStatus($postData['status'])
                ->setImageurl($postData['imageurl'])
                ->save();

            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setgalleryData(false);

            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setgalleryData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            return;
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

I got below this error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

make sure before you need to create folder **`media/Gallery`**

```
public function saveAction()
    {
        if ( $this->getRequest()->getPost() ) {
            try {

                $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
                $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('imageurl');
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png')); // Your Format Here
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'Gallery'.DS;                
                $img = $path. $_FILES['imageurl']['name'];
                $filename = $uploader->getNewFileName($img);
                $uploader->save($path, $filename);
                $galleryModel = Mage::getModel('gallery/gallery');                
                $galleryModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                    ->setTitle($postData['title'])
                    ->setDescription($postData['description'])
                    ->setStatus($postData['status'])
                    ->setImageurl($filename)
                    ->save();
                //var_dump($uploader);exit();

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setgalleryData(false);

                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setgalleryData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                return;
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you posted the form without uploading an image. Make sure that the form has the `enctype='multipart/form-data'` attribute.

Comment: I need to create admin phtml also

Answer (score 0):

As Fabian says and what I understand as per your screenshot you need to add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` for that in your `Form.php` of your module add below code.

```
 $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id' => 'edit_form',
        'action' => $this->getUrl(
            'adminhtml/controller/action',
            array(
                '_current' => true,
                'continue' => 0,
            )
        ),
        'method' => 'post',
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data' //add this line 
    ));
```

**EDIT**

```
 $fieldset->addField('file', 'file', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('gallery')->__('Image'),
        'class'     => 'disable',
        'required'  => true,
        'name'      => 'imageurl',
    ));
```

Comment: I changed that also still not upload I think I missed something in savefunction()

Comment: provide your addFeild code

Comment: $fieldset->addField('imageurl', 'image', array(
                        'label' => Mage::helper('gallery')->__('Image'),
                        'name' => 'imageurl',
                        'required'  => true,
                        'note' => '(*.jpg, *.png, *.gif)',
                        ));

Comment: @Develop check Edit part

Comment: File was not uploaded. i got this error

Answer (score 0):

The issue happen with me.
I fixed the issue by edit code on block form (example: app/code/local/Leric/Blog/Block/Manage/Blog/Edit/Form.php)

Add 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data' to form:

```
$form = new Varien_Data_Form(
        array(
             'id'     => 'edit_form',
             'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
             'method' => 'post',
             'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
        )
    );
```